# angular JS access attribute from an array of objects

Tags: angularjs, json

```
$completed = [Object { count(1)="7", gid="306"}, Object { count(1)="1", gid="311"}]
```

How do I get `count(1) = 7` in an HTML template?

```
<div class="{{ completed | filter : group.gid }}">
```

so

```
{{ completed | filter : group.gid }}
```

evaluates to

```
[{ "count(1)":"7","gid":"306"}]
```

I just need '7'?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
<div class="{{(completed | filter: group.gid)[0]["count(1)"]}}" >
```

See the working demo:

```js
var app = angular.module("sa", []);

app.controller("FooController", function($scope) {

  $scope.group = {
    gid: 7
  };

  $scope.completed = [{
    "count(1)": "7",
    gid: "306"
  }, {
    "count(1)": "1",
    gid: "311"
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="sa" ng-controller="FooController">
    {{(completed | filter: group.gid)[0]["count(1)"]}}
</div>
```

Comment: No sorry! didn't work ! i tried the same with single quotes around 'count(1) but no luck